# How can I enable a WinForms or WPF project in F#?

Tags: visual-studio, f#

I have the very latest version of Visual Studio 2017 installed. I selected F# language support and F# desktop support. After restarting and going to File -> New Project I was expecting to see an option to start a new WPF or WinForms project for F# but I don't have any such options. Only console, library, ASP.NET core, and the tutorial.

How can I enable or find the new project templates for F# desktop applications?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As far as I know, there are no "out of the box" templates for WPF or WinForms on F# but (at least in VS2015) there were a set of community templates for WPF apps. To be honest, you don't *need* a template really, especially if you use the FSXaml project which makes it pretty easy to do it by hand (https://github.com/fsprojects/FsXaml).

Comment: That looks like a promising option. Can the XAML files be edited with the built in designer when using this method?

Comment: @MatthewMacFarland Yes, the XAML files can be edited with the built-in designer.

Answer (score 29):

You can create both WPF and WinForms applications in F#. There is no template for it, but it is certainly possible and many people do this. To create a simple WinForms application, you can do the following:

- Create a new console application. Go to project properties and change "Output type" in the "Application" page from "Console application" to "Windows Application"
- Right click on "References" in the project and add reference to "System.Windows.Forms" and "System.Drawing" (in the "Framework" tab).
- Replace the code in `Program.fs` with the following:

  ```
  open System.Windows.Forms

  let f = new Form()
  f.Controls.Add(new Label(Text="Hello world!"))
  Application.Run(f)
  ```

For anything bigger, you will probably want to use a nice F# GUI library such as the [FsXaml](https://github.com/fsprojects/FsXaml) project mentioned by Isaac or [Gjallarhorn](https://reedcopsey.github.io/Gjallarhorn/), but the basic first steps will be the same - create a console project, make it a windows project and then add relevant references to GUI frameworks.

Comment: I'm glad to see it's fairly simple to work around the lack of a project template. I'm assuming that if I go this route with Windows Forms I will need to create the form layout and controls placement in code without the help of the visual designer. Is that correct?

Comment: "'m assuming that if I go this route with Windows Forms I will need to create the form layout and controls placement in code without the help of the visual designer. Is that correct? " @Matthew MacFarland yes, you are right, so better option for F# is to choose WPF.

Comment: If you choose WPF with MVVM, there is also the option to put the views (XAML) in a C# project, and have the viewmodels and models in F#. Though not as elegant as more F#'ish options like FsXaml, MVC, Gjallarhorn and Elmish.WPF, I have found this to be less troublesome, and also faster for me, due to far more learning resources available.

Answer (score 11):

This isn't an easy answer. There is no built-in project template for those projects because neither the Windows Forms nor the WPF designer understand F#. We just got the ASP.NET Core templates for F# so we shouldn't complain... much.

On the other hand, a Winforms or WPF application is just C# code. Anything you do in the designer ends up as code in the form file. A Winforms or WPF application are "just" Console applications that set up the proper environment and create the forms and controls.

This is actually *easier* using XAML and WP, especially if you use MVVM or a similar architecture. That's because you can develop the XAML markup separately from the F# code and bind your data to XAML. You can even create a WPF Class library project, create Windows, pages and controls there without any code and then use them in your F# project.

There are a few libraries that make this easier. One option is [Elmish.WPF](https://github.com/Prolucid/Elmish.WPF). You can create the XAML pages and windows in a separate project and then create models etc in F#, bind them together and start the main form. If you check the repo's example most of the code defines records and commands as F# functions, eg :

```
type ClockMsg =
    | Tick of DateTime

type ClockModel =
    { Time: DateTime }

type Msg =
    | ClockMsg of ClockMsg
    | Increment
    | Decrement
    | SetStepSize of int

type Model = 
    { Count: int
      StepSize: int
      Clock: ClockModel }
```

and

```
let init() = { Count = 0; StepSize = 1; Clock = { Time = DateTime.Now }}

let clockUpdate (msg:ClockMsg) (model:ClockModel) =
    match msg with
    | Tick t -> { model with Time = t }

let update (msg:Msg) (model:Model) =
    match msg with
    | Increment -> { model with Count = model.Count + model.StepSize }
    | Decrement -> { model with Count = model.Count - model.StepSize }
    | SetStepSize n -> { model with StepSize = n }
    | ClockMsg m -> { model with Clock = clockUpdate m model.Clock }
```

Binding them together is relatively simple :

```
let view _ _ = 
    let clockViewBinding : ViewBindings<ClockModel,ClockMsg> =
        [ "Time" |> Binding.oneWay (fun m -> m.Time) ]

    [ "Increment" |> Binding.cmd (fun m -> Increment)
      "Decrement" |> Binding.cmdIf (fun m -> Decrement) (fun m -> m.StepSize = 1)
      "Count" |> Binding.oneWay (fun m -> m.Count)
      "StepSize" |> Binding.twoWay (fun m -> (double m.StepSize)) (fun v m -> v |> int |> SetStepSize)
      "Clock" |> Binding.vm (fun m -> m.Clock) clockViewBinding ClockMsg ]
```

And running the entire application

```
[<EntryPoint;STAThread>]
 let main argv = 
     Program.mkSimple init update view
     |> Program.withSubscription subscribe
     |> Program.runWindow (Elmish.CounterViews.MainWindow())
```

The code above comes from the [Counter](https://github.com/Prolucid/Elmish.WPF/tree/master/src/Samples/Elmish.Samples.Counter) sample. The XAML views are defined in the [CounterViews](https://github.com/Prolucid/Elmish.WPF/tree/master/src/Samples/Elmish.Samples.CounterViews) project. You can even delete the `.cs` files and the project will compile just fine.

Comment: I am very excited about this option! We have been studying Elm for a while and are very impressed with it. It will be very cool if we can use that to build desktop apps too.

Comment: If you like the idea of doing Elm-ish UIs in F#, you may also be interested in the SAFE stack for web development.  https://safe-stack.github.io

Answer (score 3):

And coming "soon" to an IDE near you:

“You can expect two releases from us in 2019, .NET Core 3 and .NET Framework 4.8.”

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/05/07/net-core-3-and-support-for-windows-desktop-applications/

Comment: This is article you reference is very helpful and encouraging about the future of Windows desktop development! It will be great is F# gets first class project templates and tooling support in this new version of .NET core.