# f# visual studio code gui How using open System.Windows.Forms on Mac osx

Tags: user-interface, f#

I want to make an gui form in f# visual studio code or f# visual studio.

From [How can I enable a WinForms or WPF project in F#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50373607/how-can-i-enable-a-winforms-or-wpf-project-in-f)! but i don't see "...This will be a console application, so next select the project properties and change the Application | Output type from Console Application to Windows Application..."
[This image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyvpC.png)

Likewise [Creating an F# WinForms application](https://medium.com/@vivainio/creating-a-windows-forms-gui-with-f-968b3ae75a82) but it doesn't work.
It opens with visual studio (not code).
I see just this but doesn't want to go out
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdjfp.png)

I have both visual studio and visual studio code.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Use Avalonia or Xamarin.Forms or something else. WinForms (classical) and WPF are stick to Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You are using Visual Studio for Mac, which is quite different than normal Visual Studio for Windows. It was formerly named Xamarin Studio and you might get more useful search results if you use the old name.

To change the project type, you'll need to go to project options. [Here is a documentation with screenshots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/managing-solutions-and-project-properties?view=vsmac-2019) on where this is located - it does not show F# project, but it will be in a simlar place.

Also note that you can reference `System.Windows.Forms` from a console application and use it there too - so if you cannot figure out how to change the project type, you can start just by creating forms from a console application - and then change the type later.